# How to create Response from String?(Rust-Rocket)

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I tried to implement the Responder trait for "MyConfig" struct.
But I don't know how to create Response (including the body whose type is String) which can be return from function.

I tried this code.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyConfig {
    body: String,
}

impl<'r> Responder<'r> for MyConfig {
    fn respond_to(self, _req: &Request) -> response::Result<'r> {
        let body: String = self.body.clone();
        Response::build()
            .status(Status::Ok)
            // .raw_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .sized_body(Cursor::new(body.as_str()))
            .ok()
    }
}
```

This can't compile, and shows this error.

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `body`
  --> src/main.rs:53:9
   |
53 | /         Response::build()
54 | |             .status(Status::Ok)
55 | |             // .raw_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
56 | |             .sized_body(Cursor::new(body.as_str()))
   | |                                     ---- `body` is borrowed here
57 | |             .ok()
   | |_________________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body` is a local variable and `body.as_str()` is a reference to that local variable. The reference doesn't live long enough to be included as part of the Result returned from the function.

Since you don't need `body`for anything after using it in `Cursor::new()`, could you pass it directly rather than as a reference:

```
.sized_body(Cursor::new(body))
```

---

ETA: I found this example:

```
Response::build()
    .sized_body(Cursor::new(format!("{}:{}", self.name, self.age)))
```

(from https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/response/trait.Responder.html)

They're calling `Cursor::new()` with a String rather than a reference, so `Cursor::new(body)` should work.

Come to think of it, though, since you're passing `self` directly into the function rather than as a reference, maybe you could skip creating `body` entirely and just say:

```
.sized_body(Cursor::new(self.body))
```

Comment: Ömer Erden, thanks. I've fixed the indentation in my other posts based on your example.